# What is a millisatoshi? I thought satoshi is the smallest unit?

Tags: lightning-network, satoshi, divisibility

I encountered 'millisatoshi' (msat) while browsing Lightning Network..., see screenshoot below:

[image: Taken from https://lnmainnet.gaben.win/]

And subsequently I found it mentioned here:

https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/blob/master/README.md#sending-and-receiving-payments

Obviously, I am curious... I thought satoshi is the smallest unit?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not a mistake, it's literally a thousandth of a satoshi. A satoshi is the smallest unit for bitcoin, but lightning can transact with even smaller units while channels are open. The amount is [rounded down](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/master/lnwire/msat.go#L22-L24) to the nearest satoshi when the channel is closed and broadcast to the blockchain to adhere to bitcoin's limit.