# Looking for Source of an Old Idea About Subdividing Satoshis

Tags: consensus, bip, divisibility

I remember seeing an old idea but unfortunately I didn't bookmark it and now I'm struggling to find the source again. Maybe someone will remember it and be able to point me to the source?

It was something like:

Have a consensus (SF) rule that allows swapping 1-sat for a 0-sat UTXO which has the number of fractions recorded as something like `<fracSats> OP_DROP` appended to the Script, e.g. 1-sat would convert to a 0-sat with `100 OP_DROP` for 1/100 subdivision. Then, rules would enforce that these fracs add up correctly within the scope of the TX.

From PoV of old nodes, it would be a bunch of 0-sat inputs creating a bunch of 0-sat outputs, valid by consensus but currently prohibited by relay rules.

When someone collects 100 fracSats on the input side, they'd get a 1 full sat back on the output side, I don't remember how this was supposed to work without violating consensus of old nodes, maybe the UTXO would still be 0 but miners would copy the UTXOs locking bytecode in coinbase TX and credit it with 1 sat.

Comment: That doesn’t sound economically viable. Why would you spend dozens to hundreds of sats to create an output worth a fraction of a sat?

Comment: Viable or not, I want to find the source of this idea.

Comment: I know this is not what you are looking for, but c-lightning implements mili-satoshi: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/69700/what-is-a-millisatoshi-i-thought-satoshi-is-the-smallest-unit which is probably a more reasonable implementation of this even though I have heard it causes its own slew of issues.

Comment: Perhaps this thread: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5330102.0

Comment: Nice find, the one I can't find was along the same lines, yeah! I think what I remember seeing was older and I think it tried to specify transitions from/to regular sats to/from subdivided sats.