# Discrepency with TX amounts with TBTC

Tags: bitcoind

I have the following transaction on the testnet:

```
dc5b627a93ffaca1fe02a4352406c218be17fc3e6d47cfefe7e3890037b689ad
```

It shows like this:

[image]

Notice that the amount is 1993.07(..) TBTC

With BitcoinD, I received the following:

```
Status: 90 confirmations
Date: 12/13/2017 15:56
From: unknown
To: mz7XHbwYAnfZhmMqSsgDDPpFmSuxV2i6UF (own address, label: 5f40098e-0e0d-b642-62a2-cc966775ce7f)
Credit: 0.00859375 BTC
Net amount: +0.00859375 BTC
Transaction ID: dc5b627a93ffaca1fe02a4352406c218be17fc3e6d47cfefe7e3890037b689ad
Transaction total size: 249 bytes
Output index: 0
```

But the amount is: 0.00859375 TBTC

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is something called a change address. Your client used an unspent output of `1993.07508548 BTC` and split it into two outputs (`1993.06549173 BTC` & `0.00859375 BTC`). The larger output is considered change back to the sender. I would imagine the `0.008 BTC` output is yours as that is the output displayed on your client.

If for some reason you wish to spend this `0.008 BTC` and the amount you wish to send is `0.004 BTC`, the output of this transaction will act as the unspent output of the new transaction you wish to make. The total transacted will be `0.008 BTC` even though your only sending `0.004 BTC`.

[Here is some documentation on unspent outputs](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4301/what-is-an-unspent-output)