# What will happen if all bitcoin nodes are pruned?

Tags: bitcoin-core

Does Bitcoin handle the case where all nodes are pruned?

How a new node would get the full Blockchain?

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/72617/13866

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all nodes were pruned a new node would keep making connections looking for an unpruned peer forever and fail to sync.  If instead almost all were pruned it would simply take a longer time than today to get connected to them and start syncing.

Comment: There are not kind of master nodes that don't allow purning, to help avoid "fail to sync"?

Comment: I don't understand how you think that would work... If your name begins with "A" you would only be permitted by the UN to run a non-pruned node? :)  In practice this isn't a concern today because only a few percent of nodes are pruned.