# Who has named 10e-8 BTC "Satoshi"?

Tags: history, terminology, satoshi-nakamoto, satoshi

When and where did the term come up for the first time? Did Satoshi Nakamoto comment on the naming?

Answer (score 5):

I'll list the mentions I've found in reverse chronological order.

1. It first showed up on StackExchange on [August 30, 2011](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/114/what-is-a-satoshi).

   > However, I often hear the term Satoshi as if it was a monetary unit.
2. rebuilder discussed the divisibility of Bitcion on [March 23, 2011](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=4816.msg70427#msg70427).

   > I'll use the term "Satoshi", as previously coined by others, to mean the current smallest available Bitcoin unit.
3. On [February 18, 2011](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=3574.msg50593#msg50593), kiba said,

   > I can't wait to use satoshi to denote a very small fraction of bitcoin.

   marcus_of_augustus replied,

   > 1 satoshi = 1 microbitcent (smallest denomination)
   >
   > 100 million satoshis = 1 bitcoin
   >
   > Are we agreed?

I cannot find anything earlier on bitcointalk.

> Did Satoshi Nakamoto comment on the naming?

I cannot find a searchable copy of his writings. If I can, I'll update this answer. However, his postings were already tapering off at February 2011, so probably not.