# Is it possible to buy half of a full bitcoin?

Tags: buy-bitcoins, divisibility

I've noticed that certain products online do not require a full bitcoin to purchase. My question is do you need to start with one full bitcoin in order to make a purchase of such items?

Comment: Related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/21204/is-it-possible-to-pay-part-of-a-bitcoin-to-someone

Comment: You are free to pick whichever answer you deem best, but I do think my answer is a little more comprehensive than the accepted one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can purchase any amount of Bitcoin, from $10 USD worth, to $100 USD worth, to a full Bitcoin. It is divisible up to eight decimal places, and you can purchase/send/receive any amount or fraction of a full coin.

Comment: This is technically wrong, the minimum amount is 1/100000000 Bitcoin.

Answer (score 9):

No, you can transfer fractions of bitcoins easily. From the [Myths](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Myths) section of the Wiki:

> One Bitcoin is divisible down to eight decimal places. There are really 2,099,999,997,690,000 (just over 2 quadrillion) maximum possible atomic units in the bitcoin system.
>
> The value of "1 BTC" represents 100,000,000 of these. In other words, each bitcoin is divisible by up to 10<sup>8</sup>.
>
> As the value of the unit of 1 BTC grew too large to be useful for day to day transactions, people started dealing in smaller units, such as milli-bitcoins (mBTC) or micro-bitcoins (μBTC).